# I would like my external screen to mirror my laptop screen. How do I do this?

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

My work computer is a laptop running 20.04.6. I have an external monitor.
I use virtual workspaces.
At present it seems like my external monitor is appended to the right side of my laptop
monitor within the same virtual workspace. This mean that the most important stuff is never
on my external monitor, which is the only monitor I want to view.
What I really want is for my external screen to function much as it did when I had a desktop and it was the only screen. I can do that by opening up the laptop, waiting for
the screen to become active, then closing it, waiting for my external screen to become active, and then logging on. However, doing this every time I am away from my computer is making me a little crazy. It seems like if the screens were mirrored this would take care of the problem.
thanks

Comment: On many laptops there is a *fn* key combination that alternates how multiple screen configurations are used (ie. internal only, external only, internal+external mirrored, internal+external side-by-side etc) which is the easiest way I find to achieve it (*allows you to do something different when required too*) though I don't normally use GNOME as my default, but it's what I'd have tried & usually use.  *I use desktops, thus my laptop use is occasional & thus this approach may not be ideal if I relied it daily, but I don't recall having to ever wait except ~1.5secs for it to wake on connection*

Comment: Wow that made it easy. thanks